# How do I set the default CJK font on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, japanese

I dislike MS Mincho: it's too thin, doesn't get anti-aliased, and has an excessive amount of hooks.

Unfortunately, anything that is full-width gets rendered in MS Mincho by default on any program.

I've been looking all over the place, including in the Microsoft IME settings, to no avail. Where can I change the default CJK font from Mincho to something else?

Comment: You should list some programs where you find this issue, as examples.

Comment: @user3169 *Every* program handles fullwidth this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no registry key to do this; I believe it's hardcoded.

So I settled with MacType, which hooks to processes and overrides ClearType.

One feature it has is to allow you to override/replace specific fonts, including CJK ones, with other fonts, or to just turn on regular ClearType for those specific fonts.